# Performance for a PostgreSQL view query

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have a normal view which was migrated from SQL Server 2000 to PostgreSQL 11 which executes fine in SQL Server, but in PostgreSQL it is taking more than double the time, which is too long.

I did vacuum of tables and created indexes, but maybe I am missing something. I need some help in fine tuning the query.

```
SELECT h.bg AS bg,
    count(*) AS cnt,
    sum(h.retail_score) AS retail_score
   FROM ( SELECT x.bg,
                CASE x.void_category
                    WHEN 'DEPARTMENT STORE'::citext THEN 0.6
                    WHEN 'THEATERS/CINEMA'::citext THEN 0.5
                    WHEN 'SUPERCENTER'::citext THEN 0.35
                    WHEN 'CLOTHING AND APPAREL'::citext THEN 0.3
                    WHEN 'FOOTWEAR/SHOES'::citext THEN 0.2
                    WHEN 'HOME SPECIALTY'::citext THEN 0.2
                    WHEN 'HOME IMPROVEMENT'::citext THEN 0.15
                    WHEN 'OFFICE SUPPLY/SERVICES'::citext THEN 0.15
                    WHEN 'PET SUPPLIES/SERVICES'::citext THEN 0.15
                    WHEN 'BOOKSTORE'::citext THEN 0.15
                    WHEN 'RESTAURANT - FINE DINING'::citext THEN 0.15
                    WHEN 'GROCERY STORE'::citext THEN 0.15
                    WHEN 'SPORTING GOODS'::citext THEN 0.12
                    WHEN 'SPECIALTY RETAIL'::citext THEN 0.1
                    WHEN 'HOBBIES, TOYS AND CRAFTS'::citext THEN 0.09
                    WHEN 'OTHER FOOD/BEVERAGE'::citext THEN 0.08
                    WHEN 'RESTAURANT - CASUAL'::citext THEN 0.07
                    WHEN 'CONSUMER ELECTRONICS'::citext THEN 0.07
                    WHEN 'FITNESS AND GYMS'::citext THEN 0.05
                    WHEN 'GENERAL MERCHANDISE'::citext THEN 0.05
                    WHEN 'PHARMACY/DRUG STORE'::citext THEN 0.04
                    WHEN 'PAYDAY LOAN'::citext THEN 0.02
                    WHEN 'HAIR, SKIN AND NAILS'::citext THEN 0.01
                    WHEN 'RESTAURANT - OTHER'::citext THEN 0.01
                    WHEN 'RESTAURANT - QUICK SERVICE'::citext THEN 0.01
                    WHEN 'COFFEE SHOP'::citext THEN 0.01
                    ELSE 0::numeric
                END AS retail_score
           FROM sometable x
          WHERE x.void_include = 'Y'::citext) h
  GROUP BY h.bg;
```

Execution Plan:

```
"Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=100341.22..155233.07 rows=78181 width=53) (actual time=19217.400..73474.255 rows=138934 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: sometable.bg"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=100341.22..152692.19 rows=156362 width=53) (actual time=19216.226..72095.206 rows=278778 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=99341.20..133644.11 rows=78181 width=53) (actual time=18448.896..45748.827 rows=92926 loops=3)"
"              Group Key: sometable.bg"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=99341.20..100452.06 rows=444342 width=31) (actual time=18448.677..21747.908 rows=355865 loops=3)"
"                    Sort Key: sometable.bg"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 19064kB"
"                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10912kB"
"                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13016kB"
"                    ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_ix_xd_here_9 on sometable  (cost=0.43..47026.01 rows=444342 width=31) (actual time=0.197..746.601 rows=355865 loops=3)"
"                          Index Cond: (void_include = 'Y'::citext)"
"Planning Time: 0.470 ms"
"Execution Time: 73499.182 ms"
```

I would like to see what I did wrong or forgot and learn to improve the SQL query.

Based on suggestion from Laurenz, I tried the below: but still not good... :(

```
SET work_mem = '256MB';
"Finalize HashAggregate  (cost=98417.89..99395.15 rows=78181 width=53) (actual time=40369.734..40511.007 rows=138934 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: sometable.bg"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=80240.80..96854.27 rows=156362 width=53) (actual time=38567.902..38978.588 rows=276820 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=79240.80..80218.07 rows=78181 width=53) (actual time=38350.897..38449.107 rows=92273 loops=3)"
"              Group Key: sometable.bg"
"              ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_ix_xd_here_9 on sometable  (cost=0.43..47026.01 rows=444342 width=31) (actual time=0.173..677.385 rows=355865 loops=3)"
"                    Index Cond: (void_include = 'Y'::citext)"
"Planning Time: 0.333 ms"
"Execution Time: 40546.180 ms"

SET work_mem = '1024MB';

"Finalize HashAggregate  (cost=98417.89..99395.15 rows=78181 width=53) (actual time=35633.509..35717.539 rows=138934 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: sometable.bg"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=80240.80..96854.27 rows=156362 width=53) (actual time=34612.949..34783.491 rows=277896 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=79240.80..80218.07 rows=78181 width=53) (actual time=34369.871..34446.030 rows=92632 loops=3)"
"              Group Key: sometable.bg"
"              ->  Parallel Index Scan using idx_ix_xd_here_9 on sometable  (cost=0.43..47026.01 rows=444342 width=31) (actual time=0.176..585.221 rows=355865 loops=3)"
"                    Index Cond: (void_include = 'Y'::citext)"
"Planning Time: 0.337 ms"
"Execution Time: 35735.606 ms"
```

Comment: Can you show the SQL Server version? Need to see if you run the same casting of types.

Comment: Instead of the big case statement have you tried putting those values into a table (or just a CTE) and joining to it?  You could eliminate the subquery.

Comment: Inner join helps, but what I noticed is when I have the case statement, the query performance goes down. What I did was keep static data into another table like a lookup and did an inner join, but looks like case statement is the culprit in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase `work_mem` to speed up that query.

Then the slow sort can be performed in memory, and you can probably even get a `HashAggregate` instead of a `GroupAggregate`, which avoids the sort altogether.